# Adding Sprites to Canvas in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, sprite

As requested, I'm giving a more detailed description of the problem...

First off I have this MXML:

```
<mx:Panel x="270" y="10" width="690" height="680" id="mainContainerPanel">
    <mx:Canvas x="270" y="10" width="670" height="640" id="canvas" initialize="onInit()">
        <mx:Script>
            protected function onInit():void
            {
                spiro = new Spirograph(canvas);         
            }
        </mx:Script>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Panel>
```

This passes the tag object to the constructor of my main AS3 class file. This works fine, where in the constructor I have:

```
function Spirograph(canvas:Canvas):void
{   
    mainContainer = canvas;
    mainContainer.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
    mainContainer.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 670, 640);
    mainContainer.graphics.endFill();
}
```

At the moment, I am adding all Sprite objects to the mainContainer by using a wrapper class called SpriteUIContainer:

```
package includes
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    public class SpriteUIContainer extends UIComponent
    {       
        public function SpriteUIContainer(sprite:Sprite)
        {
            super();
            this.explicitWidth = sprite.width;
            this.explicitHeight = sprite.height;
            this.x = sprite.x;
            this.y = sprite.y;
            addChild(sprite);
        }
    }
}
```

which is used in the following way:

```
private var circCentre:Sprite = new Sprite();
circCentre.x = mainContainer.width / 2;
circCentre.y = mainContainer.height / 2;
circCentre.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xD0B917); 
circCentre.graphics.beginFill(0xF2DF56, 0.2);
circCentre.graphics.drawCircle(20, 20, 50);
circCentre.graphics.endFill();
mainContainer.addChildAt(new SpriteUIContainer(circCentre), 1);
```

The circCentre Sprite never appears on screen and I don't understand how I can get it to appear.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'attached' do you mean you are adding new sprites to the UIComponent using the addChild method?

If so; You'll have to add code to size and position that new 'sprite' relative to the other objects in the container.  There is no such code in your example.  I recommend implementing this code in updateDisplayList().

More information on updateDisplayList() is in this [Flex Component Lifecycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html) documentation.

If you need more help, you'll have to expand on how your adding new sprites to the UIComponent instance; and perhaps show an example where you add more than one.

Comment: Hey, I have re-written the question now, I hope it helps because I am so confused by Flex right now. Really appreciate some pointers.

Comment: I've given up on Flex, going back to what I know and love: Flash

Comment: @AlexW Im sorry to hear that.  I don't know where you skills/knowledge lie; but, Flex is a definitely intended for a different market than Flash Pro.  There are a lot of moving parts to Flex;  so coming up the learning curve if you are not already familiar with Java, .NET, or some other programming language (and related concepts) would be hard.

Comment: For my requirements, using Flash itself is better, since I'm not making a data driven application, but much more animated. I can see why Flex is good, but it's not the right tool for this job :)

Comment: @AlexW No argument.  For something animation centric, I would also consider Flex a poor choice.